# How to add next/back page navigation to a multi-page blog post on a Quarto website

Tags: quarto

Quarto websites offer the functionality to add "previous" and "next" buttons at the bottom of a page to navigate between full-website sections and subsections.

[image]

These are visible at the bottom of their own Quarto documentation: https://quarto.org/docs/websites/

[image]

I would like the same functionality but for a single blog post on my made-with-quarto website.  I want the blog post to be a tutorial with 8 major steps and each step to be it's own page -- I find this structure is better than one super-long page with all 8 steps and it's better than trying to squeeze the content for each step onto a revealjs or powerpoint slide.

How can I make a multi-page blog post with previous/next buttons? Is this functionality possible with YAML options in my .qmd file?

```
---
title: "Tutorial as blog post"
page-navigation: true          <-???
----
```